# np.pad significantly slower than concatenate or assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

Given a list of `n` integer arrays of variable lengths (length always less than 500), my goal is to form a single matrix of size `(n, 500)`, the arrays shorter than 500 will be padded with a given constant in the front. However, I noticed that np.pad, which is designed to pad values, is actually very slow compared to other methods, see benchmark code below:

```
import random
import time

import numpy as np


def pad(arr):
    retval = np.empty((500,), dtype=np.int64)
    idx = 500 - len(arr)
    retval[:idx] = 100001  # pad value
    retval[idx:] = arr  # original array
    return retval


a = [np.random.randint(low=0, high=100000, size=(random.randint(5, 500),), dtype=np.int64) for _ in range(32)]

# approach 1: np.pad
t = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    b = np.array([np.pad(cur, pad_width=(500 - len(cur), 0), mode='constant', constant_values=100001) for cur in a])
print(time.time() - t)

# approach 2: np.concatenate
t = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    b = np.array([np.concatenate((np.full((500 - len(cur),), 100001), cur)) for cur in a])
print(time.time() - t)

# approach 3: assign to an empty array
t = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    b = np.array([pad(cur) for cur in a])
print(time.time() - t)

b1 = np.array([np.pad(cur, pad_width=(500 - len(cur), 0), mode='constant', constant_values=100001) for cur in a])
b2 = np.array([np.concatenate((np.full((500 - len(cur),), 100001), cur)) for cur in a])
b3 = np.array([pad(cur) for cur in a])
print(np.allclose(b1, b2))
print(np.allclose(b1, b3))
print(np.allclose(b2, b3))
```

Output:

```
5.376873016357422
1.297654151916504
0.5892848968505859
True
True
True
```

Why is np.pad so slow? (actually 10 times slower than assigning to empty array). The above custom pad() can actually be more optimized by simply creating a single np.empty of size `(n, 500)`, which is even faster, but for comparison fairness, I still did padding per row. I have also tried commenting others out and benchmarking one by one, but the result is similar, so it probably isn't something like caching issue

Comment: `np.pad` is written in python, and available for viewing.  It makes no promises about being fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably* because [the function is pretty complex to begin with and does a whole bunch of validation and preparation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/arraypad.py#L534) before it gets to the actual padding.

Then again, `np.concatenate` can't do e.g. any of the various `mode`s `np.pad` can.

Comment: Thanks, I always assumed that predefined numpy functions would be faster than implementing on my own, since there are a lot of people working on optimizing it. I noticed that many preparations in np.pad are for non-constant padding only, no idea why they choose to put these preparations outside if statements and cause such a significant overhead

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't what you were asking about but if you need a faster way this is probably about as fast as you can get with numpy:

```
t = time.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    b = np.full((len(a), 500), 100001)
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        b[i, -len(v):] = v
print(time.time() - t)
```

It's faster because you allocate all the memory in advance and don't do any unnecessary copying.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is still quite helpful. I forgot that I can initialize the array with np.full at first place.